# not sure how to make one line of code work in python

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I am incredibly new to programing, my professor gave me this bit of python code with a clear error on the second to last line, I am not sure how to write this code so that it doesn't error out?

things I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)

b = a[4:8]
print b
```

This returns [3 4 5 6 7] but apparently this is wrong. After this I'm not sure of any other way to express what my professor wants? I have asked her to clarify but nothing helps :/

Here is the original code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)

b = a[a > 3 & a < 8]
print b
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: 3 isn’t greater than 3. That’s why your first attempt was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parenthesis:
`b = a[(a > 3) & (a < 8)]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the nature of [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in Python. The `&` has higher precedence than `>` or `<`, so the original expression is essentially evaluating:

```
b = a[a > (3 & a) < 8]
```

This is clearly not what you want. You want to evaluate `a > 3`, then `a < 8`, then combine them. Also, your desired range is 3 to 7 inclusive, so:

```
b = a[(a >= 3) & (a < 8)]
```

Also note that some of these operators behave a bit differently for Numpy arrays than they would for standard Python objects. You will need to play around with this to get a feel for it, or read the relevant docs. For example:

```
>>> a > 3
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

So this evaluates whether each item in the array is > 3, and returns an array of boolean values.